# How to search in an array of objects in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the structure of my database in Ruby on Rails:

user have many notes
notes have many categories
categories have many notes

I have setup this relationship with has_many :through. I use

```
current_user.notes
```

to get the notes belonging to the user. But what is the best way to get the notes belonging to the current user that have a certain category? Am I supposed to use find methods like I would on a model? Thanks for reading.

Comment: What table are you using to join Note and Category? This is used in the query.

Comment: @tadman: I'm using a table called categorization

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
current_user.notes.all(:joins => :categories, :conditions => ["categories.name = ?", search_parameter])
```

Just a note that this will perform a query with an `INNER JOIN` to use a `LEFT JOIN`, you should use `:include`:

```
current_user.notes.all(:include => :categories, :conditions => ["categories.name = ?", search_parameter])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :notes  
   has_many :categories, :through => :notes 
end 

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end 

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :notes  
end
```

@current_user.notes.all

I think ,You should break your many to many relationship between notes and categories.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a named_scope to notes

```
  named_scope :with_categories, 
              lambda{|cat|
                { 
                  :joins => [:categories],
                  :conditions => ["categories.id IN (?)", cat]
                }
              }
```

and then you can simply use

```
current_user.notes.with_categories(1, 2)
```